# Google analytics, why have two script blocks?

Tags: google-analytics, javascript

Why does the Google Analytics script I add to my webpage need to come in two script blocks?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    try {
        var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-xxxxxxx-xx");
        pageTracker._trackPageview();
    } catch (err) { } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The first script in your quote above writes a new `<script>` loading tag into the document. The second block has dependencies that are loaded by that dynamically written script tag, so the browser has to have a chance to load and parse the script before the second block runs. If everything was in one block, the script loading wouldn't take place until the first script section ended.

Comment: +1. Specifically, the dependency is the _gat._getTracker(...) line.

Comment: The answer is confusing; the two script blocks will be executed synchronously, the first injects an asynchronously loaded script in "the old way" (not using `createElement`), so it becomes questionable if the injected script is loaded asynchronously or synchronously.  In Safari, I suspect it's async, given `document.createElement("script").async === true`.  Thus the need for the try/catch and for the snippet I'm familiar with to populate a global array which can get later picked up by that asynchronously loaded script.

Answer (score 3):

You may now wish to use the latest update to [Google Analytics](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/12/google-analytics-launches-asynchronous.html).  This offers performances improvements, enhances data collection and prevents tracking code errors.